# GENEXUS: envio de mails via gmail utilizando OAUTH2

Tags: genexus, gmail, oauth2

Ante el inminente cambio de gmail a partir del 30 de Mayo de no poder utilizar mas mails con usuario y contraseña, por el cambio de autenticacion utilizando OAUTH2.
Quiero saber que tiene implementado genexus para poder seguir ayudando a la comunidad y a sus usuarios en soporte.
Creo que este problema puede afectar a mas del 90% de los programadores, y seria muy buena una propuesta simple como nos tiene acostumbrados a hacer la gran herramienta de desarrollo que es genexus.
muchas gracias

Comment: Hace un rato largo que está la opción en gmail del application password. Explórala.

Answer (score 4):

Se está desarrollando el soporte vía OAuth2 ([SAC 50932](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?en,,,50932)), eso llevará unos días más. En todo caso implicará cambios de GeneXus y a su vez de la programación en el uso de STMP/Pop3, con lo cual migrar a esa versión será o no viable en cada situación.

Por el momento lo que funciona correctamente es "Application Specific Password" que en resumen: obtienes una password para la cuenta y luego la aplicación usa esa password. Más información en: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?50227,Special+considerations+for+SMTPSession+or+Pop3Session+with+Google+Accounts